# Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV - error when deploying to server

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, production-environment, fluent-ffmpeg

I've built a telegram bot using `telegraf`, I'm using `fluent-ffmpeg` and `@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg` packages for converting OGG audio to WAV.

Works fine locally, but when I deploy to railway.app platform, it throws an error at runtime.
`node:events:491 throw er; // unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV` 
[image: error]

Someone told to add `ffmpeg` binary via nixpkgs or aptPkgs like so:
`[phases.setup] aptPkgs = ["...", "ffmpeg"]`

Since the platform uses [nixpacks buildpack.](https://nixpacks.com/docs/configuration/file)
However, the same error persists.

Comment: Exit your whole app? Perhaps it gets killed on purpose from your hosting provider because of various reasons.

Comment: yep probably, even though i've got server resources they seem not to allow heavy computing. I've changed my provider and it's working fine now.